# Ace editor trigger event using javascript

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is there anything like

```
editor.getSession.trigger('change')
```

the reason I want this is because the editor goes in and out of new, so when It comes back into view I need it to do its normal 'change' thing, but I dont want to wait for user input?

Currently I have

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
    editorChangeHandler()
})
```

and I just recall

```
        editorChangeHandler()
```

when I need to, but `editor.getSession.trigger('change')` is much nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`editor.session._emit('change')` would trigger editorChangeHandler, but fake change event will break undo history.

Comment: I tried this approach and got an error  `ace.js:7973 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

Comment: I had to do something like: `editor.getSession()._emit('change', {start:{row:0,column:0},end:{row:0,column:0},action:'insert',lines: []})`

Answer (score 0):

> the reason I want this is because the editor goes in and out of new,
>   so when It comes back into view I need it to do its normal 'change'
>   thing, but I dont want to wait for user input?

You may try an alternative solution to the case using [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/).

Change:

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
    editorChangeHandler()
})
```

to:

```
editor.getSession().on('change', _.debounce(function() {
    editorChangeHandler()
}, 100))
```

when you trigger a change it like:

```
editor.setValue('my change..');
```

then it will behave like your wish:

```
editor.getSession.trigger('change')
```