# Ace Editor - Custom keybind for paste

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

The paste functionality in Ace is currently handled through events.  Is there a way to add a custom key binding for the paste event?  I've tried the following with no such luck (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020105/ace-editor-trigger-event-using-javascript)):

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
  name: "customPaste",
  bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-q", mac: "Command-q"},
  exec: function(editor) { 
    console.log("customPaste");
    editor.session._emit('paste');
  }
});
```

The key binding is recognized (as indicated by the console output), but it does not appear to be triggering a paste event.

Comment: you can't paste via JS, otherwise any site could snoop your clipboard, like they used to be able to in IE6...

Comment: @dandavis Then how does Ace perform pastes from the clipboard?

Comment: i'm not familiar, when does it paste? if the answer is "when you press [ctrl]+[v]", then it's the OS doing the pasting, not ACE... the firing of an event is a symptom of a paste, not a cause.

Comment: Now that I look a little closer, I don't believe ace is performing pastes, but rather capturing paste events and performing actions (http://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.onPaste).  I just want to add a key binding for triggering a paste event on the editor (i.e. user presses Ctrl-q and it acts just like if user pressed Ctrl-v)

Comment: i know exactly what you want to do, but i'm sorry to say it's impossible, as least using browser javascript...

Comment: Then what is a viable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this using normal javascript.
On chrome you can whitelist your site using an extension, and then call `document.execCommand("paste", null, null)`

here's how cloud9 does that: [extension](https://github.com/c9/core/blob/1adba6a59f2f73d1b816bdaa56a62a78042aebb7/build/browser_extensions/chrome/manifest.json#L7), [execCommand](https://github.com/c9/core/blob/1adba6a59f2f73d1b816bdaa56a62a78042aebb7/plugins/c9.ide.clipboard/html5.js#L139)